# What are the necessary and/or sufficient conditions allowing us to write $f(x,y)$ in the form of $g(x)+h(y)$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions, continuity

I am trying to suggest a model connecting two independent parameters $x$ and $y$ to the dependent parameter $r$. I know that $r$ depends on both $x$ and $y$ in the model. $r$ increases with the increase of $y$ and decreases with the increase of $x$. I want to simplify $r=f(x,y)$ into two functions $g(x)$ and $h(y)$ so I can find their functional forms separately given a dataset. For this purpose, it's helpful to write $f(x,y)=g(x)+h(y)$.

Could you please tell me:

1. if I do the simplification, what kind of restrictions I am imposing on $f$?
   (like I need to believe that $f'_x$, derivative of $f$ with respect to $x$, does not depend on $y$)
2. in general $x$ and $y$ are independent of each other but for the $f(x,y)$ I can also write $f_1(x,y-x)$ or $f_2(x,\frac{y-x}{x})$ .so for the second parameter just the ratio or difference does work. In this case are there any differences? do I need any restrictions or assumptions on $x$ and $y$ that can allow writing $f(x,y)$ in the form of $g(x)+h(y)$?

edit:
"I think my question is what are the necessary and/or sufficient conditions allowing us to write $f(x,y)$ in the form of $g(x)+h(y)$?"

I know it's a bit vague and I'm sorry.

Please let me know what you think that's really helpful.
Thank you!

Comment: Most functions of two variables are not separable in this manner.   Your derivative test is fine, but of course it's only useful if your functions have derivatives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a function $f$ (with domain $\Bbb R^2$) can be represented as sum $f(x, y) = g(x) + h(y)$ then
$$ \tag{*}
 f(x, y) - f(x, 0) - f(0, y) +f(0, 0) = 0 \quad \text{for all $(x, y) \in \Bbb R^2$}.
$$

Conversely, if  $(*)$ is satisfied then $f(x, y) = g(x) + h(y)$ with
$$
\begin{align}
 g(x) &= f(x, 0) \, ,\\
 h(y) &= f(0, y) -f(0, 0) \, .
\end{align}
$$

This shows that

> $(*)$ is a *necessary and sufficient condition* for a decomposition $f(x, y) = g(x) + h(y)$.

(Of course one can also consider $f(x, y) - f(x, y_0) - f(x_0, y)+f(x_0, y_0)$ instead, with arbitrary $(x_0, y_0) \in \Bbb R^2$.)

For sufficiently regular functions $f$ we have the following equivalent conditions:

- If $f$ is diffentiable then $(*)$ is satisfied if and only if $f_x(x, y)$ does not depend on $y$, and $f_y(x, y)$ does not depend on $x$.
- If $f$ is twice differentiable then $(*)$ is satisfied if and only if the mixed derivative $f_{xy}(x, y)$ is identically zero.

Comment: thanks a lot! And before that is there any way to know if we would be able to write f in this form? like the necessary and/or sufficient conditions allowing us to write f(x,y) in the form of g(x)+h(y).

Comment: @Pebra: I have rewritten the answer a bit to make it more clear that we have a necessary and sufficient condition. Please let me know if anything is still unclear.